# Stand-alone application to run and learn JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Since it's recommended as one of the best books on the subject, I started reading David Flanagan's "[JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th ed](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)".

Besides the browser-based solutions mentioned in the book (Chrome's Console seen through Wrench > Tools) or Firefox's Firebug addon, is there a stand-alone application that can run, debug, and profile JS code?

Thank you.

Comment: Does Node.js count? If so then that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`nodejs`](http://nodejs.org/). It has a command line interface as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `debugger;` on your js code and when the browser will get to this line you can debug your js in Visual Studio for example.

You can also use [F12 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by clicking F12 on IE to debug your js application

Answer (score 0):

if online JavaScript consoles are qualified then you can look at

http://jsconsole.com/ .
http://jsfiddle.net